# How to only send password reset email when the provider is email/password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following:

```
public void sendEmailToExistingUser(String email) {
    mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) emailSent.setValue(true);
    });
}
```

The task is successful even when the previously registered user has a different provider e.g: Facebook.
That sent email will **not reset** the facebook login in case the user logged in with Facebook in the past, and I do not want to reset facebook password.

**EDIT:** My understanding is that a forgotten password case always happens prior to login, so getCurrentUser() is always null.

**Question:** Can I add a condition to avoid sending an email whenever provider id is not firebase email/password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)). It will lookup the associated sign-in methods for the provided email.

However, keep in mind that password reset can sometimes be used for non-password users as a means to recover their account or if the user forgot that they previously signed in with Google, etc. You can probably warn the user before they reset that they previously signed in with the specified provider.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could retrieve the current user and check their provider.

```
public void sendEmailToExistingUser(String email) {
    boolean isEmailPassword = false;

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
            // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
            String providerId = profile.getProviderId();
            if (providerId.equals("password")) {
                isEmailPassword = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isEmailPassword) {
        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) emailSent.setValue(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but if a user is not signed because he forgot his password and trying to reset it, then getCurrentUser() will always return null, then isEmailPassword will always be false. Can we get the providerId prior to user being signed in?

Comment: @RedM Yes, you can get the `providerId` prior to the user being signed in using the Firebase Admin SDK. See [`providerData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html#providerdata)

Comment: Does it mean that it is not doable from client? It has to be done from the server?

Comment: Per @bojeil answer, providerData is not the only option. fetchSignInMethodsForEmail can check whether the provider is email_password or something else. This can be done from the client.